# Wrong argument type, PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am working from a book, learning python with raspberry pi and I'm a bit stumped on this because I receive this type error. My IDE is spitting this message out below and I am unsure if it's a constructor type issue

> control_window = TurtleControl(babbage) TypeError:
>   'PySide.QtGui.QWidget' called with wrong argument types:
>   PySide.QtGui.QWidget(Turtle) Supported signatures:
>   PySide.QtGui.QWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget = None, 
>   PySide.QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags = 0)

```
import turtle
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *


class TurtleControl (QWidget):
    def __init_(self, turtle):
                super(TurtleControl, self) .__init__()
                self.turtle = turtle

                self.left_btn = QPushButton("Left", self)
                self.right_btn = QPushButton("Right", self)
                self.move_btn = QPushButton("Move", self)
                self.distance_spin = QSpinBox()


                self.controlsLayout = QGridLayout()
                self.controlsLayout.addWidget(self.left_btn, 0, 0)
                self.controlsLayout.addWidget(self.right_btn, 0, 1)
                self.controlsLayout.addWidget(self.distance_spin,1, 0)
                self.controlsLayout.addWidget(self.move_btn,1, 1)
                self.setLayout(self.controlsLayout)

                self.distance_spin.setRange(0, 100)
                self.distance_spin.setSingleStep(5)
                self.distance_spin.setValue(20)

                self.move_btn.clicked.connect(self.move_turtle)
                self.move_btn.clicked.connect(self.move_turtle_right)
                self.move_btn.clicked.connect(self.move_turtle_left)

# set up turtle
window = turtle.Screen()
babbage = turtle.Turtle()

# Create a QT application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
control_window = TurtleControl(babbage)
control_window.show()

# Enter QT application main loop
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: typo, change `def __init_(self, turtle):`  to `def __init__(self, turtle):`. 
the `__init__` method must have 2 underscores before and after, in your case you have 2 underscores to the left but one to the right.

Comment: Can you actually mix `turtle` and `PySide` in a single program like this?

Comment: as @abarnert says you should not mix 2 GUI, they will be blocked between both.

Comment: Also: is this code from the book? If so, that's fine (as long as the license allows for it), but tell us where in the book, and ideally link to the source and/or chapter (if either or both are online). Then we can compare what you have to what they have and spot what you might have gotten wrong, or tell you that the book is out of date and won't work with current Python or Qt, or whatever.